# diferencia en eficiencia entre int y byte java

Tags: java

Existe realmente alguna diferencia entre un dato de tipo int y un tipo byte, yo se que int es mas fácil de "entender" en cuanto a lectura y escritura de código, pero byte ocupa en teoría menos espacio de almacenamiento, digo "en teoría" porque alguna vez alguien me dijo que la maquina virtual de Java almacena la información en espacios de 4-bytes y que entonces manejar un byte es igual que manejar un int, puesto que los 3 bytes sobrantes son desperdiciados, ¿que tan cierto hay en esto, y en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución hay realmente alguna diferencia?
 En cuanto a la estructura del código que tan buena practica es hacerlo en un programa, yo se que hacerlo para ahorrarse 6 o 9 bytes no tiene sentido y en ese caso lo mejor es usar un int puesto que el ahorro es realmente insignificante y que no vale la pena "sacrificar la legibilidad del codigo", pero si se manejan alrededor de 20 mil datos ¿hay alguna diferencia notable o es mejor seguir usando int por cuestiones de comodidad, cual seria una cantidad considerable de datos para que realmente valga la pena usar byte y no int?

Comment: en los libros de certificación OCA de java explican que la JVM hace una promoción a `int`, y de acuerdo a lo que entendí, la JVM esta optimizada para manejo de int, tambien si se declara un tipo de dato `long` pero no se coloca el sufijo `L` este lo almacena como un `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Ahórrate quebraderos de cabeza y usa int

La diferencia entre ambos es **irrelevante en el mejor de los casos, inexistente en la mayoría**.

Teóricamente un byte ocupa menos que un int, pero dependiendo de la JVM que estés usando y el compilador JIT de turno, puede ser que tus bytes estén promocionándose a int, o puede que no. Incluso tengo entendido (esto no es seguro) que el hardware puede jugarte malas pasadas en este tipo de diferenciaciones.

Este tipo de **mini-micro optimizaciones** muy probablemente no te van a librar de falta de memoria. Es mucho más probable que eso te pase por (por ejemplo) intentar cargar grandes archivos en memoria o por tener objetos muy pesados sin liberar.

---

Vivimos en una época en la que la memoria es barata, las optimizaciones por la máquina virtual abundantes y el tiempo de desarrollo, caro. Primero encárgate de escribir un código fácil de mantener y seguir, siguiendo las buenas prácticas, y deja que el compilador se encarge de estas cosas. [**Sólo cuando te veas ante el problema busca una solución**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI)

Comment: Muchas gracias, respecto a mi duda, he alcanzado a ver en muchos lados lo de la "promoción a int" y si, pensandolo bien es mejor usar los datos como int